# Multiple File Uploader in PHP with Text fields

Tags: php, mysql, file, uploader

I want to create a multiple Drag and Drop file up-loader, in php.  Again i have a code that can upload the file. But In the form I will be having text fields too. When i tried to work on that, the file is being uploaded properly, But my entries are not being saved in database. Since in the drag and Drop up-loader i don't have a button, i cant use Post Method to pass the variable.

Comment: I dont know what are you using - im using `plupload` and it have a way to send additional data   like post vars with sending the file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried ajax ?

With jQuery :

$.ajax({
url: "your url",
data: your data serialized,
success: 
});